# PSTricks in TeX Live 2014

Tags: pstricks, texlive

Using XeLaTeX then `dvips` leaves blank spaces where the PSTricks drawings are supposed to be. How do I repair this?

I should add that I am using a Windows 7 PC. Also, I am a very naive user, but stuff that works on a Solaris machine does not work on the PC.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. It's not necessary to sign your questions (as [there is already a box with your username below it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: Is XeTeX not supposed to function with the `xdvipdfmx` driver, not `dvips`?

Comment: @fpast XeTeX runs `xdvipdfmx` automatically under most conditions, so presumably the OP simply says `dvips` from habit.

Comment: "[S]tuff that works on a Solaris machine does not work on the PC." That should be a good reason for abandoning Windows! `:)` P.S. I hope your problem gets solved.

Comment: PSTricks for XeTeX in TeX Live 2014 with Ghostscript 9.15
does not work on all platforms.

Comment: I live inside Emacs; what I have in my .emacs on the PC is:
$param = @ARGV[1];

$HOME = "c:\\users\\ed";
$HOME_BIN = "$HOME\\bin";

if ( $param =~ /(.*)\.tex$/i )
{
  system "C:/texlive/2014/bin/win32/xelatex.exe ${1}.tex >> $HOME\\.log";
  system ("C:/texlive/2014/bin/win32/dvips -f ${1}.dvi -o ${1}.ps  >> $HOME\\.log");
  system ("C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.10/lib/ps2pdf -o ${1}.pdf  -f ${1}.ps >> $HOME\\.log");

}

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Ghostscript 9.15, the problem is known
and it was already fixed in the TeX Live repository.
In order to repair the problem in TeX Live 2014, use
Ghostscript 9.10. Gs 9.14 is known to have other
problems for TeX.
Note that, unfortunately, the pre-installed Ghostscript
in the latest TeX Live 2014-win32 is version 9.15.
In order to use your own Ghostscript, which I recommend 9.10,
define an environment variable

TEXLIVE_WINDOWS_EXTERNAL_GS=gswin32c.exe

and set the command PATH for the 9.10 gswin32c.exe.

Comment: I don't understand: dvips seems unrelated to ghostscript; the ps file generated by dvips is where the problem shows up.  Are you saying that the figures are there but that gsview does not show them?

Comment: Are you really using dvips for .xdv files created by xelatex?
Please use xdvipdfmx instead.

Comment: I thought that I HAD to use dvips to get the pstricks stuff.

Comment: How do I do this?  I know how in Unix, but how in Windows?!define an environment variable

TEXLIVE_WINDOWS_EXTERNAL_GS=gswin32c.exe

and set the command PATH for the 9.10 gswin32c.exe.

Comment: I try to translate into English, since
I'm on Japanese Windows 7:

(1) start menu (left click)

(2) computer (right click)
    property (choose by left click)

(3) setting of system-details (left click, needs administrator?)
    property --> environment variable (left click)

It will be selfevident hereafter. Set environment variables of
a user 'you'.(example):

name(N) --- TEXLIVE_WINDOWS_EXTERNAL_GS
value(V)--- gswin32c.exe

name(N) --- PATH
value(V)--- c:\Program Files\gs9.10\bin;PREVIOUS_CONTENTS_IF_EXIST

Comment: Okay!  Now the ps is correct, but the pdf is not.  How do I generate the pdf file from the ps file?  I thought it was ps2pdf, but does not work.

Comment: XeTeX and XeLaTeX creates pdf, not ps, via xdvipdfmx.
Are you really saying about XeTeX?
I susspect that you are using latex. PSTricks works best
in the case of latex + dvips.

Comment: Here is what I am doing (now): latex.exe file.tex followed by dvips.exe (in both cases the 2014 versions).  The result now is a file with only the figures, the text is gone!  When I then run ps2pdf (v. 9.10) I get a pdf file with the figures only.  I confess I do not know what I am doing--I am used to a Unix environment and am now trying to get things working on a Windows PC.  I am lost.  I get perfect output (ps and pdf) when I run this stuff under Solaris.

Comment: If you don't use PSTricks on XeTeX, it is not needed to
install Ghostscript 9.10. The pre-installed Ghostscript 9.15
works fine to make pdf from ps file obtained by latex + dvips.
Basic usage of latex, dvips, ps2pdf is similar between
Windows and Unix. But if you are familiar with Unix,
I recommend to work on Unix.

Comment: But as I said, then I get only the figures, not the text!  I have no choice but to move to a Windows PC; I am forced by circumstances, so I must get this working!

Comment: I think usual fonts are downloaded in the `PS` file, in the
default setting of `psfonts.map` in the TeX Live. Thus there
should be no problem to obtain visible text in the `PDF`
created by `ps2pdf`. Special fonts such as `CJK` fonts need some cares.
Anyway, remove the definition of the variable
`TEXLIVE_WINDOWS_EXTERNAL_GS`.
Then the default setting in the TeX Live for the Ghostscript 9.15
should work fine to create pdf from ps:
`latex a_source`, `dvips a_source`, `ps2pdf a_source.ps a_source.pdf`.

Comment: I still get no text, just the pstricks diagrams.  The log of what is happening is too long to put here, but everything executed is from 2014.  No error are indicated--the file is just the pictures.  One thing that bothers me is that it says:  This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014/W32TeX) (preloaded format=latex).  What is pdfTeX?

Comment: The actual binary of latex in TeX Live is pdftex
on all platforms. If you give a MWE (minimal working example)
someone may be able to help you.

Comment: Working on an MWE.

Comment: I entered the Twilight Zone:  Now I cannot get things to fail--even the file that led me to start this thread.